# redirect current url controller to new url controller zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

My current url is in the format **example.com/controller1/method1/parameters**. I want to redirect from controller1 to controller2 like this **example.com/controller2/method1/parameters**

There are several methods present in controller1. So I cannot write redirect methods in all my methods. I just want to change the current controller name to my new controller name with the same parameters.
Is there a zend property or class that I can use.

Comment: I just want to change the current controller name to my new controller name with the same parameters.

Comment: Do you want to get rid of `Controller1`, or you just want some actions to be redirected to `Controller2`?

Comment: No, I just want to change my controller name only using the zend arhitecture.

Comment: Then, why don't you just change the name? (class + file)

Comment: No, I can't fo that as my Controller1 has like nearly 50+ functions in which most of them are not in use. Due to this I created a new Controller2 which has only limited functions.